# How to remove the Effective Permission in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, user-roles

I dont want to set the Effective permission when creating the role permissions. I want to set only for the allow checkbox selection.

When i check the "Site Owner Permissions" , automatically selected to all the Effective checkbox. I dont want to select the Effective selection.

Please refer the attached image.

Role-Effective checkbox image:

[image]

Any suggestion on what i might be doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The site owner permission is the most powerful one. If you want to have finer control over each setting, just don't check that permission.

Comment: Ya actually i didn't check anything else. only i check selection for site owner permission checkbox. others i didn't checked. but in the effective checkbox checked based on the site owner permission.

Comment: Right, so why did you check the site owner permission for that role?

Comment: I have customised Site Owner option from textbox to dropdownlist for my forum concept. So i need to enable the site owner for one particular role. If i select the site owner checkbox only it will be placed on the screen. That's why i need to select on that. So is there any possibilities to do my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Each module can define it's own permissions and the effective permission is determined based on the permission definitions:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Custom-permissions/

Orchard supports so called [ImpliedBy permissions](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-permissions/#implied-permissions) and there are also hardcoded stuff like Administator role can do anything.

I struggled with this issue too and i solved it by using a custom authorization event handler to avoid the hardcoded Administator role handling:

```
public abstract class ExplicitPermissionAuthorizationEventHandler : Orchard.Security.IAuthorizationServiceEventHandler
{
  // public
    public ExplicitPermissionAuthorizationEventHandler(Orchard.Data.IRepository<Orchard.Roles.Models.UserRolesPartRecord> aUserRolesPartRecords)
    {
      mUserRolesPartRecords = aUserRolesPartRecords;
    }

    public void Checking(Orchard.Security.CheckAccessContext aContext) {}
    public void Adjust(Orchard.Security.CheckAccessContext aContext) {}

    public void Complete(Orchard.Security.CheckAccessContext aContext)
    {
      if (aContext.Granted && IsModulePermission(aContext.Permission) && aContext.User != null)
      {
        var lIsAdministrator = mUserRolesPartRecords.Fetch(r => r.UserId == aContext.User.ContentItem.Id && r.Role.Name == "Administrator").Any();

        if (lIsAdministrator)
        {
          // check whether permission is explicitly assigned as Orchard grants all permissions by default when user is in role "Administrator"

          var lHasPermissionExplicitly = mUserRolesPartRecords.Fetch(r => r.UserId == aContext.User.ContentItem.Id &&
            r.Role.RolesPermissions.Any(p => p.Permission.FeatureName == ModuleName && p.Permission.Name == aContext.Permission.Name)).Any();

          if (!lHasPermissionExplicitly)
            aContext.Granted = false;
        }
      }
    }

  // protected
    protected abstract bool IsModulePermission(Orchard.Security.Permissions.Permission aPermission);
    protected abstract string ModuleName { get; }

  // private
    private Orchard.Data.IRepository<Orchard.Roles.Models.UserRolesPartRecord> mUserRolesPartRecords;
}
```

This should get you an idea how to use authorization handlers.